# Help calculating two integrals-- generalized and definite

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

> The first one is to calculate
>
> $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(1+4x^2)^2} dx.$$

I think this one should be solvable with the method of substitution but I tried using $t=4x^2$ which didn't work well, or where I have miscalculated something.

> The second one is, for every $n\in\mathbb N$, to calculate
>
> $$\int_{-1}^{1} (1-x^2)^n dx.$$

So, I really don't know how to solve the second integral. Maybe through the use of $n=1,2,3,\cdots$ and look for any patterns?

Comment: The first integral is solved by the substitution $x=\frac{\tan t}{2}$ and the second one by the substitution $x=\sin t$ or by Euler's Beta function. Did you really try something? They are quite trivial questions.

Comment: If you consider $f(a)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{1}{a+4x^2} dx$ then you find the first integral by differentiation under the integral sighn. The second one can be solved by the beta function-gamma function relationship.

Comment: Also note for the first if you differentiate under the integral sign you'll have the negative of what you want. (After you plug in $a=1$).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\,{#1}\,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\Li}[1]{\,\mathrm{Li}_{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\,\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\,\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$

1. \begin{align}
   \color{#f00}{\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{\dd x \over \pars{1 + 4x^{2}}^{2}}} & =
   \int_{0}^{\infty}{\dd x \over \pars{1 + x^{2}}^{2}} =
   -\lim_{\mu \to 1}\,\partiald{}{\mu}\int_{0}^{\infty}{\dd x \over  x^{2} + \mu}
   \\[5mm] & =
   -\lim_{\mu \to 1}\,\partiald{}{\mu}
   \pars{\mu^{-1/2}\int_{0}^{\infty}{\dd x \over  x^{2} + 1}} =
   -\lim_{\mu \to 1}
   \pars{-\,\half\,\mu^{-3/2}\,\,\,{\pi \over 2}} = \color{#f00}{\pi \over 4}
   \end{align}

   ---
2. \begin{align}
   \mc{J} & =
   \color{#f00}{\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{\dd x \over \pars{1 + 4x^{2}}^{2}}} =
   \int_{0}^{\infty}{\dd x \over \pars{1 + x^{2}}^{2}}\ =\
   \overbrace{\int_{0}^{\infty}{\dd x \over x^{2}\bracks{\pars{1/x - x}^{2} + 4}}}
   ^{\ds{\mc{J}}}
   \\[5mm] 
   \stackrel{x\ \mapsto\ 1/x}{=} &\
   \underbrace{\int_{0}^{\infty}{\dd x \over \pars{1/x - x}^{2} + 4}}_{\ds{\mc{J}}}
   =
   \half\pars{\mc{J} + \mc{J}} =
   \half\int_{0}^{\infty}
   {1 \over \pars{1/x - x}^{2} + 4}\,\pars{1 + {1 \over x^{2}}}\,\dd x
   \\[5mm] &
   \stackrel{\pars{x - 1/x}\ \mapsto\ x}{=}\,\,\,\,\,
   \half\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{\dd x \over x^{2} + 4} =
   {1 \over 4}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{\dd x \over x^{2} + 1} =
   \color{#f00}{\pi \over 4}
   \end{align}

Answer (score 4):

As Jack mentioned, we have
$$I=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(1+4x^2)^2} dx=2\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(1+4x^2)^2} dx$$
Set $x=\frac{1}{2}\tan \theta$, we have
$$I=\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \cos^2\theta \,d\theta=\frac{1}{2}\beta\left(\frac 12,\frac 32\right)$$
**Second Integral**
$$J=\int_{-1}^{1} (1-x^2)^n dx=2\int_{0}^{1} (1-x^2)^n dx$$
Set $x^2=t$, we have
$$J=\int_{0}^{1} t^{-\frac{1}{2}}(1-t)^ndt =\beta\left(\frac{1}{2},n+1\right)$$

Comment: what is that $\beta (x,y)$ thing? i haven't coem close with that yet, so it would be a lot, if i would get an explanation, if it's not too much to ask

Comment: Please check it https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function

Comment: Also, see http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BetaFunction.html

Comment: well i found this integarl in a part of calculus, that didn't use beta function yet, but okay, i will compare other answers and this one to see if it's the saem result, perhaps the solution was meant to be without the $\beta $ symbol i guess
But thanks for the answer :)

Comment: The beta function is usually written with capital beta $\mathrm{B}(x,y)$, not small beta $\beta(x,y)$.

Comment: @GEdgar Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

Alternative approach for the first integral: by Residue Theorem
$$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{dx}{(1+4x^2)^2}=2\pi i\cdot\mbox{Res}\left(\frac{1}{(1+4z^2)^2},\frac{i}{2}\right)\\=2\pi i\cdot-\frac{1}{4}\frac{d}{dz}\left(\frac{1}{(1-2iz)^2}\right)_{z=i/2}=2\pi i\cdot\left(-\frac{i}{8}\right)=\frac{\pi}{4}.$$

Alternative approach for the second integral: for $n>0$,
$$I_n:=\int_{-1}^1 (1-x^2)^n dx=\left[ (1-x^2)^n x\right]_{-1}^1 -n\int_{-1}^1 x(1-x^2)^{n-1} (-2x) dx\\
=-2n\int_{-1}^1 (1-x^2)^{n-1} (-x^2+1-1) dx=-2n I_n+2nI_{n-1}.$$
Hence 
$$I_n=\frac{2n}{2n+1}\cdot I_{n-1}=\frac{(2n)\cdot (2n-2)}{(2n+1)\cdot(2n-1)}\cdot I_{n-2}=\cdots=\frac{(2n)!!}{(2n+1)!!}\cdot I_0=2\cdot \frac{(2n)!!}{(2n+1)!!}.$$

Answer (score 2):

For the first one, integrating by parts, 
$$\int\dfrac1x\cdot\dfrac x{(1+4x^2)^2}dx$$

$$=\dfrac1x\int\dfrac x{(1+4x^2)^2}dx-\int\left(\dfrac{d(1/x)}{dx}\int\dfrac x{(1+4x^2)^2}dx\right)dx$$

$$=-\dfrac1{8x(1+4x^2)}-\int\dfrac{dx}{8x^2(1+4x^2)}$$

Now,
$$\int\dfrac{dx}{x^2(1+4x^2)}=\int\dfrac{1+4x^2-4x^2}{x^2(1+4x^2)}dx$$

Comment: and the last one can be divided into "two sumands" and easier to caclualte, right?

Comment: @MathIsTheWayOfLife, Yes, left for you.

Answer (score 0):

The first integral can also be evaluated using Glaisher's theorem, which says that if:

$$f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^n c_n x^{2n}$$

then we have:

$$\int_{0}^{\infty}f(x) dx = \frac{\pi}{2}c_{-\frac{1}{2}}$$

if the integral converges and where an appropriate analytic continuation of the series expansion coefficients has to be used (e.g. factorials replaced by gamma functions). This is a special case of [Ramanujan's master theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramanujan%27s_master_theorem).

In this case we can easily obtain the series expansion. Differentiating the the geometric series:

$$\frac{1}{1+u} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^n u^n$$

yields:

$$\frac{1}{(1+u)^2} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^n (n+1)u^n$$

We thus have:

$$\frac{1}{(1+4 x^2)^2} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^n (n+1)4^n x^{2n}$$

This means that $c_n = (n+1)4^n$ and $c_{-\frac{1}{2}} = \frac{1}{4}$, the integral from minus to plus infinity is thus $\frac{\pi}{4}$.